# Is Dijkstra algorithm faster than DFS?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, dijkstra

Maybe it is a silly question, but I have been using Dijkstra algorithm for some implementations related with graphs. Now I have to implement a script in which I need to find distances between nodes. Whick one would be a better option, using a Dijkstra algorithm with weights equal to one or implementing the DFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm with all weights equal is exactly equivalent to **BFS** (not DFS). DFS isn't appropriate for finding shortest paths, since it explores longest paths first, but BFS is.

If you know in advance that all weights are equal, there's no sense in using a priority queue and implementing full Dijkstra's; you can use a plain queue and get BFS with less code and slightly less overhead.